# No cookies when SSR

Tags: sveltekit

When SSR a page, the authentication cookies from the client are not passed with the fetch request.

I am using this code to fetch the date.

```js
export const load = (async ({ fetch }) => {
    const user= await fetch("https://subdomain.domain.com/api/user", {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'include',
    });
    return {
      user
    };
}) satisfies LayoutLoad;
```

When i am in development mode. (backend on address: http://127.0.0.1:5000/ and frontend on address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/) everything works fine.

But when i am deploying the services to my live system (backend on address https://subdomain.domain.com/api and frontend on address: https://subdomain.domain.com/) the ssr returns an Error 401, because the authentication failed (probably because no cookies were send with the request).

I dont know if this is relevant, but i am using nginx with this configuration:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    proxy_set_header Origin $http_origin;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
}
```

I have no idea why it works in developer mode and not in live mode. Does anyone have any ideas what I can try or test?

Comment: How do you deploy your SSR?

Comment: I am using the node-adapter to build the Svelte Kit application and then i am starting it with node.

Comment: I think you need the [`handleFetch`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handlefetch) hook.